# Nuget dependency not being added accordingly

Tags: dependencies, nuget

I have a nuget package called "Package A". Package A is using the package called Newtonsoft.Json

When my package is packed the .nuspec looks like this

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
   <metadata>
      <RedactedGeneralInfo>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" />
      </dependencies>
   </metadata>
</package>
```

After installing package A to my project its packages.config looks like

```
<packages>
    <package id="mycompany.productname.packageA" version="8.3.0.4" targetFramework="net461"/>
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net461"/>
</packages>
```

Everything looks fine. I've download my packageA, it noticed I have a dependency on newtonsoft and therefore it also added newtonsoft to my packages.

However, when I'm looking at my project references I only see "mycompany.productname.packageA" added as a reference. The expected "Newtonsoft.Json" reference inside my project is missing.

Newtonsoft is also missing from the project in general. When I build my project it compiles without any errors, however on the first line of code where newtonsoft should be used an error will be thrown because my project doesn't have a reference to newtonsoft.json.dll.

What am I doing wrong or what should I do differently to make sure I get the correct reference?

***What have I tried already?:***

directly adding newtonsoft.json.dll to packageA using my .nuspec file. This works partly, because it does make sure I have a reference to newtonsoft.json.dll. However the reference I get is "../packages/packageA/newtonsoft.json.dll" (hard reference) instead of a "../packages/Newtonsoft.json/newtonsoft.json.dll" (soft reference, I can update newtonsoft independently from package A)

**note:** adding the reference manually or having a reference inside of another package is not my desired outcome.

***Desired outcome (1 trough 4 are already happening, I only need 5 now):***

1. project B downloads PackageA.
2. project B notices packageA has a reference to the newtonsoft.json package
3. project B downloads newtonsoft.json package
4. Project B adds a reference to packageA.dll
5. project B adds a reference to newtonsoft.json.dll